# table view detail disclosure iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am having a table view with titles in each row.

Now i need when i click on the row it should take me to the next view (detail view).

I have connected the row and the new view with segue "Information Detail Segue".

Now here is the code:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Information Detail Segue"]) {

    InformationDetailTVC *informationdetailTVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    informationdetailTVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    informationdetailTVC.delegate = self;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    self.selectedInformation = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"Passing selected role (%@) to RoleDetailTVC", self.selectedInformation.title);
    informationdetailTVC.information = self.selectedInformation;
}
```

But when i am running, and clicking on the cell, the control doesn't go to this loop. Infact when i click the cell, it just becomes blue and doesn't load the new view.

Can any one tell me what am i missing?

Comment: did you write this code inside a didSelectRowAtIndexPath: ?

Comment: nopes...is it required? i was following this link: http://timroadley.com/2012/02/14/core-data-basics-part-3-editing-and-deleting/ and here the code is working without this function.

Comment: i wrote this code under prepareForSegue Method...but it is not going inside that method only.

Comment: Is it going in prepareForSegue method's if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Information Detail Segue"])  clause?

Comment: nopes...i checked by putting nslog stmts...its not going in that loop only. I also verified the segue name...thats also fine. Also, the disclosure indicator accessory is also not showing up in the simulator.

Comment: then nslog the segue.identifier just before the if statment to check what identifier comes.

Comment: it is not going in prepare for segue method only...

Comment: The usual issue is forgetting to change the class from UITableViewController to your custom class in the storyboard...

Comment: i checked that too...everything is set to my custom class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try implementing:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

don't forget to set your delegate and datasource (usually on the xib file)

Comment: Thanks, I implemented didSeleceRowAtIndexPath method and it worked. But i am still wondering, why it didn't work with the segue?